# Award Hat multiple times or Once?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

Is each hat awarded multiple time or is it just awarded once?

Let say I have earned a *[Need For Speed](http://winterba.sh/a-need-for-speed)* Hat today and then tomorrow if I will again cast 10 votes (that's fulfill the criteria of *[Need For Speed](http://winterba.sh/a-need-for-speed)* Hat), so then will I award
*Need For Speed* Hat again?

Comment: Why would you need to? There is no point.

Comment: You can earn same hat in multiple sites, you can't earn more than one hat on same site and it's quite pointless anyway..

Comment: It's not a game. It's just fun :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. And why do we need to earn it multiple times? We can't wear multiple hats at the same time. Then why do we need to have same hat multiple times?

Proof:

Today, I answered questions with 5+ score more than one time but I have earned [Where is He?!](http://winterba.sh/where-is-he) only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can earn the hats once for each Stack Exchange site. There really is no point in earning them more than once, since you can only wear one at a time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Why do we need same hat with multiple times? It doesn't write in [FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq) but I think this isn't an option. But you can earn the same hat for different stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

Nope -- you'll just have that hat one time. However, this also means you don't need one question at +5, one at +10, and one at +15 to earn those different hats -- it's cumulative, so if one question gets to +15, you will earn all three hats.

That said, if you're active on *multiple* sites, then and only then can you earn the same hat repeatedly. Given that your hats on SO don't follow you to MSO, this is a great way to extend your hat collection and try out other sites!